# Reading CSV file in chunks of 10000 in java

Tags: csv, chunks

We have a module in our application which reads a CSV file that has around 50000 rows. currently we read the rows using buffered reader and iterate over it and store it in POJO. But when the file is read sometimes it shows OutOfMemory Error. Can anyone suggest the solution for this. Can anyone guide me to read the file in chunks of 10000

this is the sample code

```
ArrayList<sampleClass> classList=new ArrayList<sampleClass>();
try
{
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        line = br.readLine();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] columnValues = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            SampleClass obj=new sampleClass();
            if(validation1)
                obj.setproperty1(columnvalues[0]);
            if(validation2)
                obj.setproperty2(columnvalues[1]);
                ......
                ......
                ......
                if(validationN)
                obj.setproperty3(columnvalues[n-1]);
            classList.add(obj);
        }
}
catch()
{
        ...
}

return classList;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This,Hope it will help you.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            int checkCount = 0;
            int chunkTemp = 0;
            int i = 0;
            String temp = "";
            BufferedWriter writer = null;
            while ((temp = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (chunkTemp == 0) {
                    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename + i));
                }

                ++checkCount;
                ++chunkTemp;
                writer.write(temp);
                if(chunkTemp!=10000){
                     writer.newLine();
                }

                if (chunkTemp == 300) {
                    chunkTemp = 0;
                    ++i;
                    writer.close();
                }
            }
```